# Help with Analyzing NFS Architecture in a Cluster Sharing a Home Directory Across Two Servers"

Tags: linux, nfs, storage, reverse-engineering

I Am very confused because I am trying to understand the architecture without documentation,we have a NFS architecture of a cluster of PCs that share the same home directory ( Server1 is a Pc of a cluster ) and every user has a home in the Server 2 used for a specific purpose from the users. I've collected the following information from both servers:

Server 1:

Output of

```
cat /etc/exports

> /disk28 172.16.13.115(rw)  172.16.13.114(rw) ....etc
```

Output of showmount -e N/A

cat  /etc/fstab
> 172.16.15.20:/disk38   /disk38                 nfs     defaults,bg,rw 0 0
172.16.15.17:/disk36   /disk36                 nfs     defaults,bg,rw 0 0 ...etc

Server 2:

Output of

```
cat /etc/exports
>/home 172.16.14.86(rw) 172.16.37.221(rw) 172.16.11.30(rw) 172.16.11.51(rw) 172.16.37.222(rw) 172.16.37.219(rw) 172.16.37.253(rw) 172.16.10.154(rw) 172.16.11.219(rw) 172.16.12.16(rw) 172.16.12.20(rw) 172.16.12.32(rw) 172.16.12.40(rw) 172.16.12.125(rw) 172.16.12.126(rw) 172.16.12.127(rw)  ...etc
```

Output of

```
showmount -a
>All mount points on a.server:
172.16.11.219:/home
172.16.11.30:/home
172.16.11.51:/home
172.16.12.125:/home
172.16.12.126:/home
172.16.12.127:/home ...etc



cat /etc/fstab

>/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
none                    /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
none                    /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
none                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
none                    /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/hda                /media/cdrom            auto    pamconsole,fscontext=system_u:object_r:removable_t,exec,noauto,managed 0 0
```

Now, I'd like to comprehend how these servers are configured to share the home directory and how the interaction between the cluster PCs and these NFS servers works. What specific details should I be looking for in these outputs to get a complete picture of the NFS architecture?

Thanks in advance for any help or insights you can provide. I'm willing to share the full outputs if needed.

Comment: Please use [code block]s for command output, file contents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`fstab` is only part of the story, you should look at the output of the `mount` command to see what is mounted right now.

Mounts can come about by various methods, for example `autofs` and `systemd` can both mount volumes without touching `fstab`.